# Error message on find() API in CLoudboost

Tags: cloudboost

I have an error in a call using `find()` method. This is the curl:

```
curl 'https://api.cloudboost.io/data/vfzlvdumignf/Friendship/find' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://builder.site.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en,es;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,ca;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'sessionID: 5aa762d0-eec7-11e5-9e37-31a03a6b5b13' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: http://builder.site.com/projects/mygourmetlist/navigate' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"query":{"$include":[],"$includeList":[],"$or":[{"$include":[],"$includeList":[],"sender._id":"8PsRRYXf"},{"$include":[],"$includeList":[],"receiver._id":"8PsRRYXf"}]},"select":{},"sort":{},"limit":100,"skip":0,"key":"357a5306-80c9-46b2-bbb7-ce7b2b0a5470"}' --compressed
```

And this is the response:

> code:13435
> errmsg:"not master and slaveOk=false"
> message:"not master and slaveOk=false"
> name:"MongoError"
> ok:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on our end. Looks like a MongoDB hiccup. Can you please try again.

Comment: 10 minutes after posting, it was orking and I haven't seen the error anymore. thanks!